# APK to Support Phone & Tablets. (Single SourceCode with Single APK)

Tags: android, layout, apk, tablet

I am using SDP (https://github.com/intuit/sdp) to scale my App UI for all kind of devices. Will this be enough to publish my app for tablet or I need to make any declarations in Manifest file?

If yes, will I have to create different layouts ? (I don't need to add new layouts since SDP is doing all the work for layout support).

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need a separate APK for tablets and phones. Also, there is no need to create separate layouts for tablets as well if your UI is already looking as intended on it. Publishing single APK will be enough for all kinds of devices, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: No changes in the manifest file ? Like support-screen tag etc ?

Comment: By default, those attributes are set to true. Usually they are used to disable support for some densities instead of enabling. Also, when you upload an APK, you will be prompted with a list of devices that won't be able to install your APK. You can then check for any configuration change needed in your APK before publishing it to production (Play store)